# Android greenDao save entity with relation

Tags: android, greendao

I made db according the following entities:

```
Entity image = schema.addEntity("Image");
image.setTableName("Images");
image.addStringProperty("id").primaryKey();
image.addStringProperty("size128");
image.addStringProperty("size320");


Entity user = schema.addEntity("User");
user.setTableName("Users");
user.addStringProperty("id").primaryKey();
user.addStringProperty("fullName");
Property userImageIdProperty = user.addStringProperty("imageId").getProperty();
user.addToOne(image, userImageIdProperty);
```

When I try to add new user, the image isn't stored.

```
Image image = new Image();
User player = new User();
player.setId(advisorClient.getId());
player.setFullName(advisorClient.getFullName());

if (advisorClient.getAvatar() != null) {
    image.setId(advisorClient.getAvatar().getId());
    image.setSize128(advisorClient.getAvatar().getW128());
    image.setSize320(advisorClient.getAvatar().getW320());
    player.setImage(image);
}
daoSession.getUserDao().insertOrReplace(user);
```

I store it in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert the image in the database like you do with the user.

```
Image image = new Image();
User player = new User();
player.setId(advisorClient.getId());
player.setFullName(advisorClient.getFullName());

if (advisorClient.getAvatar() != null) {
    image.setId(advisorClient.getAvatar().getId());
    image.setSize128(advisorClient.getAvatar().getW128());
    image.setSize320(advisorClient.getAvatar().getW320());
    player.setImage(image);

    daoSession.getImageDao().insertOrReplace(image);
}

daoSession.getUserDao().insertOrReplace(user);
```